# Selenium python code script reproduce duplicated extracted values

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, duplicates

I am trying to scrape Order details(show below) from a webpage each page has about 15 orders, where I used selenium to click each order and then grab the specific order details, the issue is the extracted data are duplicated and after the 15th order the loop seems to return back to starting point even though the next 15 orders page is loaded.

the behavior of the webpage, is when the order link is clicked, a pop-window is opened with the order details

Customer details:

- Customer mobile
- Address, Region, Street, building , floor , Room.

Order status:

- merchant name
- Order status list => the stages for order status ( order received, accepted/canceled, being prepared, etc.. ) with time stamps

Food basket:

- sr_no -> serial number
- food_title -> meal name
  with all other details like ( quantity, price, delivery_charge, total_amount, and amount after promo)

** the food basket in the output is constant and never changes **

please find a snippet of the output :
[Sample output (masking private data)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7oilU.png)

My code:

```py
import time
import csv
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


# Set up Selenium options
chrome_options = Options()
#chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")  # Ensure GUI is off
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)


# Set up Selenium driver
webdriver_service = Service()  # Update with actual path to chromedriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=webdriver_service, options=chrome_options)


# Extract specific details for each link
def extract_details():
    #driver.get(str(link))
    #time.sleep(5)  # Delay of 2 seconds between each link

    try:
        cst_mobile = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//div[text()="Mobile"]/following-sibling::div').text.strip()
    except:
        cst_mobile = 'NA'
    try:
        address_title = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//div[text()="Address Title"]/following-sibling::div').text.strip()
    except:
        address_title ='NA'

    try: 
        region = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//div[text()="Region"]/following-sibling::div').text.strip()
    except:
        region = "NA"
    try:
        street = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//div[text()="Street"]/following-sibling::div').text.strip()
    except:
         street = "NA"
    try:      
        building = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//div[text()="Building"]/following-sibling::div').text.strip()
    except:
          building ="NA"
    try:        
        floor = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//div[text()="Floor"]/following-sibling::div').text.strip()
    except:
        floor = "NA"    
    try:
        room = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//div[text()="Room"]/following-sibling::div').text.strip()
    except:
        room ="NA"
    # Additional details - Order Status and Time/Date
    driver.implicitly_wait(5)

    order_status_elements = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.os-block-section .order-status-card')
    order_status_list = []
    for order_status_element in order_status_elements:
        try:
            status = order_status_element.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.order-st-title').text.strip()
        except:
            status= "NA"    
        try:
            time = order_status_element.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.order-st-time').text.strip()
        except:
            time ="NA"
        try:   
            date = order_status_element.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.order-st-date').text.strip()
        except:
            date = "NA"    
        order_status_list.append((status, time, date))

    # Additional details - Order Status and Expected Delivery
    try:
        merchant_name = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'div.card-header').text.strip()
    except:
        merchant_name ='NA'    
    try:
        expected_delivery = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'span.badge-danger').text.strip()
    except:
        expected_delivery = 'NA'
      

    return cst_mobile, address_title, region, street, building, floor, room, merchant_name, order_status_list, expected_delivery


def extract_food_basket():# Find and extract the food order details
    table_rows = driver.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'table.table tbody tr')

    food_orders = []
    for row in table_rows:
        try:
            sr_no = row.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'td:nth-child(1)').text.strip()
        except:
            sr_no = 'NA'
        try:    
            food_title = row.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'td:nth-child(2) strong a').text.strip()
        except:
            food_title = "NA"
        try:
            quantity = row.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'td:nth-child(3)').text.strip()
        except:
            quantity = "NA"
        try:
            price = row.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'td:nth-child(4)').text.strip()
        except:
            price="NA"
        try:
            total_price = row.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'td:nth-child(5)').text.strip()
        except:
            total_price= "NA"
                
        food_orders.append((sr_no, food_title, quantity, price, total_price))

    # Extract the delivery charge and total amount
    try:
        delivery_charge = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'table.table thead tr:nth-child(2) th:nth-child(2)').text.strip()
    except:
        delivery_charge = "NA"
    try:
        total_amount = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'table.table thead tr:nth-child(3) th:nth-child(2)').text.strip()
    except:
        total_amount = "NA"    
    # Extract the total amount after promocode
    try:
        total_amount_after_promo = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'table.table thead tr:nth-child(5) th:nth-child(2)').text.strip()
    except:
        total_amount_after_promo = "NA"
    return food_orders , delivery_charge, total_amount , total_amount_after_promo


def extract_restaurant_detail():
    try:
        contact_info_button = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,
                              "btn-primary")
        contact_info_button.click()
        time.sleep(2)
        button = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, "btn-primary")))
        button.click()
    except:
        print('***** contact info Button didn\'t clicked, 1st restaurant name = NA *****') 
        restaurant_name = "NA"
    try:    
        # Wait for the new window to pop up
        WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.number_of_windows_to_be(2))
        # Switch to the new window
        driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])
        driver.implicitly_wait(10)
    except:
        print('***** Pop-up window not shown in extract restaurant details, 2nd restaurant name= NA *****')
        restaurant_name = "NA"
    try: 
        restaurant_name = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//div[text()="Restaurant Name"]/following-sibling::div').text.strip()
    except:
        print('***** restaurant name not found in extract restaurant details, 3rd restaurant name= NA *****')
        restaurant_name = "NA"
    return restaurant_name        


# Function to extract links and details
def extract_links(element):
    # link = element.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, 'a').get_attribute('onclick') -> output str
    link = element.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '[onclick*="loadOpenDrawer"]')
    driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", link)
    driver.implicitly_wait(5)
    #link.click() -> Element click intercepted
    # Switch to the newly opened window or iframe if applicable
    try:
        if len(driver.window_handles) > 1:
            driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[1])
            driver.implicitly_wait(5)
            extract_details()
            extract_food_basket()
            driver.close() # to close the newly opened window
            #extract_restaurant_detail()
            driver.implicitly_wait(5)
            driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])
    except:
        print('***** pop-up window in extract links didn\'t open*****')

# Navigate to the start URL and login into the page
driver.get(****) # *** for confidentiality 
time.sleep(1)  # Delay to allow page to load
driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'username').send_keys(***) # *** for confidentiality 
driver.find_element(By.NAME, 'password').send_keys(***) # *** for confidentiality driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div/div/div/div/div/div/form/button').click()
driver.implicitly_wait(5) # Delay to allow page to load

#start with page order 1000
driver.get('*****/order/view/1000')

# instantiate a csv to save the desired scraped output
filename = 'Orders.csv'
with open(filename, 'a', newline='') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)   
    writer.writerow(['cst Mobile','Address Title', 'Region', 'Street', 'Building',
                        'Floor', 'Room',
                        'merchant_name','Order status list', 'Expected Delivery',
                        'food_basket' , 'delivery_charge', 'total_amount' , 'total_amount_after_promo',
                        ]
                        ) # to add 'Restaurant_name', 'order_number'
    file.close()    


# Check for pagination
current_page = 1000
base_url='****'

# Iterate through pagination links(testing phase)
while current_page <= 1001:
    driver.get(base_url + str(current_page))

    # Extract links and details from the start URL
    strong_elements = driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'strong')

    for element in strong_elements:
        extract_links(element)
        driver.implicitly_wait(3)

        # Save the details as CSV for each extracted link
        cst_mobile, address_title, region, street, building, floor, room, merchant_name, order_status_list, expected_delivery = extract_details()
        food_orders , delivery_charge, total_amount , total_amount_after_promo = extract_food_basket()
        

        with open(filename, 'a', newline='') as file:
            writer = csv.writer(file)
            writer.writerow([cst_mobile, address_title, region, street, building,
                                floor, room,
                                order_status, order_status_list, expected_delivery,
                                food_orders , delivery_charge, total_amount , total_amount_after_promo,
                                ]) # to add restaurant_name, order_numbers
            
        driver.implicitly_wait(5)
    current_page += 1
```

Expect all Extracted orders to have unique details.
Noting that NA values are permissible as sometimes the detail isn't included in the webpage